# Googleworkspace Warning when sending to group mail including external addresses

Tags: email, gmail, warnings, google-workspace

We are using Google workspace and have some group mail including external email addresses.
The domain of the group mail is the same as our organisation.
Is it possible to get warning when we mail to this kind of the group mails?